# Changing color or tint of SwiftUI ProgressView inside a SideBarView

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationbar, tint, progressview

I'm trying to customize the color or tint of a SwiftUI ProgressView that's placed within a SidebarView on a macOS app. Here's the code structure I have:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SidebarView()
            MainView()
        }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    @State private var progress = 0.8
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: MainView()) {
                Label("Blue", systemImage: "1.circle")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second Item Detail")) {
                Label("Second Item", systemImage: "2.circle")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .frame(minWidth: 150, idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: 300)
        ProgressView(value: progress) {
            Text("Label")
        }
        .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .blue))
        .tint(.blue)
        .accentColor(.blue)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var progress = 0.8
    
    var body: some View {
        ProgressView(value: progress) {
            Text("Label")
        }
        .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .blue))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The ProgressView inside MainView has its tint color customized using .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .blue)), and it works as expected.

However, the same approach does not seem to work for the ProgressView placed within SidebarView. The color remains the default and doesn't reflect the desired blue tint. I've tried using .tint(.blue) and .accentColor(.blue) on the ProgressView, but it doesn't change the color.

Is there a way to modify the tint or color of a ProgressView within a SidebarView? Any insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Trying it with an iPad (10th Gen) simulator using iOS 16.4 it seems to work fine. It's the tint color passed as parameter to ```CircularProgressViewStyle``` that seems to control it (I changed it to pink to be sure), the two modifiers that follow it have no impact. Have you only tried it in a Preview?

Comment: @BenzyNeez so this is actually for a Mac app. I should have specified that in the post. When I run it on my Mac in Xcode the CircularProgressViewStyle is the default color white/grey.